# BJT circuits under biasing

Tags: bjt

I am unable to find an answer for any of the values. I attempted to write the equations but I feel I need beta i.e current gain to reach a definitive answer here.

Could anyone please confirm that this question is unsolvable without current gain.

[image]

Comment: What's the name of the book this is this from?

Comment: @mrbean this is from our semester previous year question papers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying KVL got me this:

$$ I_E(R_E + \frac{R_B}{1+\beta} + R_C) =  9.3 $$

If \$R_B\$ were comparable with \$R_E\$, then the term \$\frac{R_B}{1+\beta}\$ would become negligible.

However, that's not the case, in fact \$R_B\$ is very large, and the influence of \$\frac{R_B}{1+\beta}\$ is strong, and significantly dependent on \$\beta\$.

I fear that the only solution in which it is not necessary to know an exact value for \$\beta\$ is if you are certain that \$\beta >> 10^3\$, which is very unlikely for a single transistor.

Answer (score 3):

When DC bias is realized with a voltage divider allowing a divider current which is approximately 10 times larger than the base current Ib we can neglect Ib. (Remember, this is the reason we are using a divider which provides a - more or less - "stiff" base voltage).

However, in the present case with a base resistor which is as large as 470k we are not allowed to neglect Ib. Simple example: For Ic=1mA and Ib=Ic/200 the voltage drop across Rb is app. 2.3 volts.

We have two equations for three unknown quantities:

**Vc=Vcc-(Ic+Ib)Rc=**Vcc-IeRc****  and **IbRb=[Vc-(0.7+IeRe)]**  with Ie, Vc and Ib unknown.

Neglecting Ib (setting it to zero) would mean Vc=(0.7+Ve)=Vb (transition between active and saturation region).

**Example**: Solving the above equations with B=Ie/B gives

Ie=(Vcc-0.7)/[Rc+Re+(470k/B)].....=1.23mA for B=200.

This expression for Ie clearly shows why Ib (resp B) must not be neglected for this calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need beta to solve or the other possibility is that questioner assumes beta is high enough that IB can be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need Beta.

The key to this configuration is that a larger Beta (or increased Beta due to temperature) produces a larger emitter voltage and a smaller collector voltage due to increased collector current (Ic = Beta * Ib).  Both these voltage changes reduce the voltage across the base resistor.  The reduced voltage across the base resistor results in reduced current into the base.  This decrease in base current partially offsets the increase in Beta.

These are the advantages of the collector and emitter feedback configuration over a simple base-biased circuit.

**Beta = 100**
[image]

**Beta = 200**
[image]

**Beta = 300**
[image]